# Test a function which uses document properties in qunit

Tags: javascript, qunit, sinon

I have a function like this which I would like to write a unit test for :

```
function A () {
    var x = document.referrer;
    //Do something with 'a' 
}
```

I would like to write a unit test, to test this function. I'm using QUnit with sinon.js for stubs and mocks. Is there a way for me to mock the document object so that I can provide a value for the referrer and test my logic? I tried assigning a value to `document.referrer` in my `setup` function, but that didn't work

**Update**

This is the test which I'm trying :

```
module("Verify Referrer", {
    setup : function () {
        this.documentMock = sinon.mock(document);
        this.documentMock.referrer = "http://www.test.com";
    }, 
    teardown : function () {
        this.documentMock.restore();
    }
});

test("UrlFilter test url in white list", function() {
    equal(document.referrer, "http://www.test.com");
});
```

I also tried using `stub`

Comment: Can you show us your test, and what you've tried so far (that doesn't work)? You should be able to create a `setup` method on your `module` and mock out the `document.referrer` property, so maybe there is an issue with how you've done it.